# How to remove a catchpoint in GDB

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

I've set a catch point in GDB to catch exceptions with `catch throw`. How do I remove it without restarting the GDB session?

Neither `delete` nor `clear` seem to be helpful here.

Comment: could you provide gdb's output when you try to remove it with `delete`?

Comment: And `info breakpoints` also

Comment: @bznein thanks, I used the wrong command format

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turned out I tried to delete it wrongly with `delete throw`.

`(gdb) info breakpoints
 Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
 2       breakpoint     keep y   0x063e3255 exception throw`

`delete 2` did the trick.